# Swift Protocol inheriting Protocol method with same name

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

While reading swift forum about exceptions I found interesting issue. One of the examples about exceptions was something like this:

```
protocol Base {
    func foo() throws -> Int
}

protocol Refined: Base {
    func foo() -> Int
}

struct Test: Refined {
    func foo() -> Int {
        0
    }
}
```

It's interesting, I thought it was typo that it would not compile, but it does. I am not sure how this does work behind the scenes. I mean when protocol adopts another protocol it adopts also its requirements. But in this case declaring same method without throws somehow satisfies also first protocol `Base`.

At the very least I expected `Test` to need to have 2 implementations of `foo`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because a non-throwing function is by definition a sub-type of a throwing function

From the Swift Programming Language book

*The throws keyword is part of a function’s type, and nonthrowing functions are subtypes of throwing functions. As a result, you can use a nonthrowing function in the same places as a throwing one.*

But you can't do it the other way around so the below code will generate an error

```
protocol Base {
    func foo()  -> Int
}

protocol Refined: Base {
    func foo() throws -> Int //error: Cannot override non-throwing method with throwing method
}
```

Also note that this is not only for protocols, if you remove the func declaration from `Refined` you can still implement the function in `Test` as non throwing.